# Decode Javascript packed binary data at server PHP side

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have HTML form with 2 controls - file input control #resume and submit button #action_cv.
Most of files I can (and want) upload to server are binary.
There is reading and packing (encoding) this data at front side (Javascript):

```
function readFile(file, callback) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = callback;
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#action_cv').on('submit', function (event) {
       let input_data = {
           resume: null,
           resume_data: null
       };
       let resume = null;
       if (($("#resume"))[0].files.length > 0) {
           resume = ($("#resume"))[0].files[0];
           input_data['resume'] = resume.name;
           readFile(resume, function (evt) {
               let data = evt.target.result;
               let bs =
                   String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data));
               input_data['resume_data'] = bs;
           });
       }
       // AJAX call with input_data skipped here...
   })
});
```

Here `data` contains raw binary data from file, and `bs` - already packed for AJAX submission to server written by PHP. My question is very simple - how to unpack this encoded (packed) binary in PHP to get original file at server side? (No need to provide writing file operation - it seems evident)

Comment: Looking for [`unpack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)? Maybe needs a `mb_convert_encoding ($data, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");` those UTF-16 code units? We don't have a multibyte problem, you have a multibyte problem. What's unicode?